# Create an array for each collection view cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a collection view with custom collection view cells.

I want to keep track of the number of times each cell is tapped and store in an array. So, my custom cell has a label, IBAction and an array.

I am able to do this by appending 1 to the array inside IBAction and printing out the count.

However, I want to access this data outside the custom cell view class. I want to have an array specific to each cell i.e. by the name

> ```
>     self.titleLabel.text!
> ```

Of course, I can't use a variable for the name of an array! (I wish I could)

How do I store data in such case?

Where and how do I need to define the array to easily store and process data?

Comment: 1) Why can't you use a variable name for the name of your array? You definitely can. You are able to use a property like anything else for an array. 2) Your custom cell subclass should not be holding the array. The cell should be responsible for showing data, your model or viewController should be responsible for holding the data like your array. Let your viewController handle the count of taps and increment it in your `didSelect` delegate method.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. It certainly makes sense to hold array outside the custom cell based on an MVC model. However, I am not sure how to do that. 

1) I tried creating an array inside the custom cell using 
>     self.titleLabel.text!
but swift throws an error
2) Also, how do we access the label outside the custom cell when there are multiple cells. I cannot use the "self" keyword 

It would be helpful if you can provide some code.

Comment: To answer that question you'll need to post your code you tried to add it to the custom cell. Then we can debug that Swift code. its possible, there most be something a bit wrong with your Swift code

Comment: I am adding code on top of this project 
http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-rearrange-uicollectionviews-through-layouts/
https://github.com/mmick66/KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Code added in KDRearrangeableCollectionViewCell.swift
`@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("This is \(self.titleLabel.text!) button!!! It works!!!!")
        buttonCount.append(1)
        print("\(self.titleLabel.text!) has been recorded \(buttonCount.count) times")
        dump(tapCounts)

    }
    
    var buttonCount = [Int]()
    
    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("Button \(self.titleLabel.text!) has been tapped!!!")
    }`

Comment: In above code if I use `var .\(self.titleLabel.text!)  = [Int]()`, swift throws an error
Output for above code:
This is Button3 button!!! It works!!!!
Button3 has been recorded 4 times
▿ 4 elements
  - [0]: 1
  - [1]: 1
  - [2]: 1
  - [3]: 1

Please also look at my comments for the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You may declare `Dictionary` that holds tap count in your `UIViewController`:

```
var tapCounts = [NSIndexPath: Int]()
let collectionView = UICollectionView()

func tapAction(sender: UICollectionViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender) {
        tapCounts[indexPath] = (tapCounts[indexPath] ?? 0) + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sharing the code 

I tried including it in my project with a modification
I replaced
>    UICollectionViewCell
with my custom class
>    KDRearrangeableCollectionViewCell"

However when I use
>    dump(tapCounts)
I get "- 0 key/value pairs"

Not sure what is wrong... Please help

Comment: @EcoApps looks like you have issue in invoke `tapAction`; did you set `target - action` to this method from your button/gesture? Also, you better share some parts of code to help us to help you

Comment: I am adding code on top of this project 
http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-rearrange-uicollectionviews-through-layouts/
https://github.com/mmick66/KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Also added 
`var buttonTapped: UITapGestureRecognizer?`
in KDRearrangeableCollectionViewCell.swift

I added and played with the code in the ViewController.swift 

`@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Hello World!")
        dump(tapCounts)
        func tapAction(KDRearrangeableCollectionViewCell, buttonTapped) 
    }`

Comment: Also modified your code 

`var tapCounts = [NSIndexPath: Int]()
let collectionView = UICollectionView()
    
    func tapAction(sender: KDRearrangeableCollectionViewCell, gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hello tapAction!!!")
        if((sender.buttonTapped) != nil){
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender) {
            tapCounts[indexPath] = (tapCounts[indexPath] ?? 0) + 1
            print("\(sender.titleLabel.text)")
        }
        }`

Comment: Moreover, I am not sure if this code should be present in KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout.swift as that file has code to handle all the long press gestures on the Collection View Cells.

Also, please look at my code in above comments in response to @Ryan-Poolos